# Removing items from a generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am trying to remove items from a generic array in Java.

For example an array `[1,2,3,4]` would become `[null,null,null,4]` if a 3 was passed in for the `n` parameter.

My issue is my method is doing nothing to the array. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test<E>
{



    private E[] queue;
    private int added = 0;
    private int removed = 0;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Test(int capacity){
   this.queue=(E[]) new Object[capacity];

    }


    public E[] getQueue(){
        return queue;
    }


    public void setQueue(E[] items){
        queue = items;
        added=items.length;
        removed = 0;

    }


    public static String formatOutput(Object[] items){
        if (items == null) return "null";
        return String.format("[%s]\n",
                             String.join(", ",
                                         Arrays.stream(items).map(o -> ((o != null) ? o.toString() : "null")).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }


    public E[] newArray(int capacity){

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E[] a= (E[]) new Object[capacity];
        return a;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E[] removeNItems(int n){
        E[] a= (E[]) new Object[n];
        if(n<queue.length){
        return null;
       }
     else{
           for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
               a= (E[]) queue[i];
               queue[i]=null;

              this.removed++;

           }}


           return a;

    }





    public boolean addNItems(E[] items){
        if(items.length+this.added>this.queue.length){


        return false;
    }
    else{
  for(int i=0; i<items.length;i++){
      queue[i]= (E) items[i];
      added++;
  }



        return true;
    }   
    }




    public int size(){
        return added - removed;
    }


    public static void main(String [] args){
        Test<Integer> test = new Test<>(10);
        System.out.print("Testing the constructor with a capacity of 10: " + formatOutput(test.getQueue()));
        System.out.println("Size of queue after operation: " + test.size());
        // testing the newArray method
        System.out.println("Testing the newArray method with a capacity of 5: " + formatOutput(test.newArray(5)));

        System.out.println("Trying to add 5 items");
        Integer[] addFive = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println("Able to add 5 items-> " + test.addNItems(addFive));
        System.out.println("Size of queue after operation: " + test.size());
        System.out.println("Array after adding 5 ints: " + formatOutput(test.getQueue()));

        System.out.println("Trying to remove 4 items");
        Object[] fourItemsRemoved = test.removeNItems(4);
        System.out.println("Items removed: " + formatOutput(fourItemsRemoved));
        System.out.println("Size of queue after operation: " + test.size());
        System.out.println("Array after trying to remove four items: " + formatOutput(test.getQueue()));



    }
}
```

Actual Output:

```
   Trying to remove 4 items
   Items removed: null
   Size of queue after operation: 5
   Array after trying to remove four items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null, null,null, null, null]
```

Expected Output:

```
Trying to remove 4 items
Items removed: [1,2,3,4]
Size of queue after operation:6
Array after trying to remove four items: [null,null,null,null,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following array method to slice out just the section you want, which it appears would be `n` to the end for your use case.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)

`E[] newQueue = Arrays.copyOfRange(queue, n, queue.length)`

Comment: For reference, that function is probably built on System.arraycopy

Answer (score 0):

Looking your whole code, I can see that you have never initialized your variable queue. At some point you have to do it, you can do it at the beginning or in the constructor.
 Well, now I see the update, a good way to go throw an array is starting with 0 and go to the length - 1 ( so you don’t get an index out of bound exceptions ) ..
 In your case, you should ask by two things, in > queu.length and if the n that is increasing is at the end.
Most important of all:
 Did you check what you are asking inside the if statement?

‘If(queue.length + remove > queu.length)’

That will be always false, you wanted to ask instead if the number of elements you will Reese are less than the length of the queue? Well it would be:
‘if(queue.length > n)’
The rest of the code is ok

Comment: I do have a constructor. Here it is

Comment: public Test(int capacity){
   this.queue=(E[]) new Object[capacity];
   
    }

Comment: @Eric Smith Mmmm it is a little confusing read it like this, could you add the complete code to the question?

Comment: I believe everything is correct but I am still not getting the correct output. I am going to try to use my editors debugger to see if that helps.